# A simple SQL Select query to crawl all connected people in a social graph?

Tags: sql, select, join, graph

What is the shortest or fastest SQL select query or SQL procedure to crawl a social graph. Imagine we have this table:

```
UId FriendId
1   2
2   1
2   4
1   3
5   7
7   5
7   8
5   9
9   7
```

We have two subset of people here, i'm talking about a sql query or procedure which if we pass:

Uid = 4 return the result set rows with `uid : {1, 2, 3}`

or if

Uid = 9 return the result set rows with `uid : {5, 7, 8}`

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: What is your SQL database, postgreSQL and Oracle have recursive queries support, but not MySQL.

Comment: Aram has asked two MySQL-related questions in the past week - it looks like that's what is being used.

Comment: Yes im using Mysql, i wanted to know the answer in general, and not a specified database.

Comment: There is no `uid = 4` in the sample data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want get all friends of someone, including n-th degree friends? I don't think it is possible without recursion.

How you can do that is explained here:
https://inviqa.com/blog/graphs-database-sql-meets-social-network

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing your values in an adjacency list, the easiest way I've found to crawl it is to translate it into a graphing language and query that.  For example, if you were working in PHP, you could use the [Image_GraphViz](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_GraphViz/) package.  Or, if you want to use AJAX, you might consider [cytoscapeweb](http://cytoscapeweb.cytoscape.org/). Both work well.

In either case, you'd `SELECT * FROM mytable` and feed all the records into the graph package as nodes. This means outputting them in [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/pub/scm/graphviz2/doc/info/lang.html) or [GraphML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/primer/graphml-primer.html) (or other graphing language). Then you can easily query them.

If you don't wish to translate the dataset, consider storing it as nested sets.  [Nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model), though a bit of a pain to maintain, are much better than adjacency lists for the kind of queries you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing your values in an adjacency list, and you want n-th degree you can simply recursively INNER JOIN the UID's. For example:

```
Select t1.uid, t2.uid, t3.uid FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.uid=t2.uid INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.uid=t3.uid
```

This query is like a DFS with a fixed depth.