# MySQL Query to Match value from one column to the same value in another colum

Tags: mysql

I have a transactional table, that has two id reference fields NEW_REF, Orginal_REF.  So in this transactional table I can have multple transactions that actually relate to the one event.  When a new event is added, it gets an NEW_REF and the Original_REF field is null.  If somehting changes about this event, a new record is created, and the new record has its Original_REF update to that of the previous NEW_REF ID.

So as an example, in my table, I have:

```
REF1 | Original_Ref
 956 | 200
 960 | null
 967 | 960
 980 | 967
 990 | 600
 991 | 700
 992 | 670
 998 | 343
1000 | 980
1001 | 778
1010 | 787
1020 | 565
```

As an example, if an event has more than one related transaction, I want to be able to have a query that would pull out all related transactions, per event.  In the above example, I would expect to see:

```
REF1 | Original_Ref
 960 | null
 967 | 960
 980 | 967
1000 | 980
```

Here Records 960 is the original record and has been updated 3 times.  Is there a way of quering my table to identify and group together related transactions per event?

Answer (score 0):

The way your table is structured, you end up having to do nested subqueries.  If your tree gets any deeper than about 3 nodes, it becomes grisly.  You might consider a table structure like this:

```
id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
parent_id int unsigned,
root_id int unsigned not null
```

An initial event record might look like this: `200, null, 200`.  A first child might be `547, 200, 200`. An nth child might be `1038, 986, 200`.

So a query for all the records for an event is simple:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE root_id= ?
```

Comment: Thanks. The table I'm looking at, through some manual work, has about 7 nodes, i.e. the maximum number of records per event has gone up to 7.  Of course, I have other tables in which I need to do this kind of analysis, and was hoping there wold be a more dynamic approach.

Comment: @user1236443: if you aren't wedded to SQL, you can dump your table into graphml which is very good at following trees.  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160117/a-simple-sql-select-query-to-crawl-all-connected-people-in-a-social-graph/7160739#7160739

Answer (score 0):

This is probably about the fastest query you can do that meets your requirements.  Note that it will not group result records by "transaction group" -- in this case, such an ordering will be very difficult to achieve using SQL alone.  (I'm assuming you already have a separate index on both columns -- if not, make sure that you do or this query will perform very poorly.)

```
SELECT a.REF1, a.Original_Ref

FROM txn AS a

LEFT JOIN txn AS b
ON a.Original_Ref = b.REF1

LEFT JOIN txn AS c
ON c.Original_Ref = a.REF1

WHERE b.REF1 IS NOT NULL
   OR c.Original_Ref IS NOT NULL;
```

You can also do this with correlated subqueries, but MySQL is notoriously poor at optimizing those as joins.

Comment: Nice, but what this returns, if I include the b and c columns is to return the values in one row 960 | null | 967 | 960 | 980 | 967 | 1000 | 980

Comment: @user1236443 That looks like exactly the result you wanted, no?

Comment: No, as above in my example. In their separate respective rows.

Comment: You want all of the results in *one row*?