# Create Group ID for linked rows using SQL

Tags: sql, graph

Is there a way, in SQL, to create an Id for 'linked groups'?

```
Source Table

+----+-----+
| Id |  Id |
+----+-----+
|  1 |   2 |
|  1 |   3 |
|  2 |   3 |
|  4 |   5 |
+----+-----+

Desired Result Table
+----+-----+-----------+
| Id |  Id |  Group Id |
+----+-----+-----------+
|  1 |   2 | A         |
|  1 |   3 | A         |
|  2 |   3 | A         |
|  4 |   5 | B         |
+----+-----+-----------+
```

**see Diagram**

[image: Also see Diagram]

Comment: mysql <> postgresql, please don't tag products not involved

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  Also, are your linked groups connected subgraphs or fully connect subgraphs?  Your examples are fully connected and the question is vague.

Comment: I believe they will always be fully connected. The source table is the result of a self join based on matched criteria. The overall problem is linking similar rows.

Comment: I'll add to that: Source table 'says' 1 is similar to 2, 1 is similar to 3, 2 is similar to 3, etc.

Comment: It seems like you are interested in finding [graph's connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)). RDBMS probably do not have that functionality. I suppose it is better to collect data, find components, and store information in DB.

Comment: yes, I agree, I found a couple of interesting articles  [Graph Algorithms in a Database: Recursive CTEs and Topological Sort with Postgres](https://www.fusionbox.com/blog/detail/graph-algorithms-in-a-database-recursive-ctes-and-topological-sort-with-postgres/620/)  and [Trees and Other Hierarchies in MySQL](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html). Also [A simple SQL Select query to crawl all connected people in a social graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160117/a-simple-sql-select-query-to-crawl-all-connected-people-in-a-social-graph)